# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound "can't find without id"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a method that toggles a boolean, but cannot get it to work at the controller level due to an ActiveRecord not found error.

My `items_controller.rb`:

```
def remove
 @item = Item.friendly.find(params[:id])
 respond_to do |format|
  if @item.toggle_approved
   format.html { redirect_to root_path }
  else
   format.html { render :show }
  end
 end
end
```

When I set the instance variable like this - `@item = Item.friendly.find(params[:id])` - I get an error that says `Couldn't find Item without an ID`. But when I set it like this - `@item = Item.find(params[:id])` - I get an error that says `Couldn't find Item with 'id'=`. I'm passing the object as an argument to the path, so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

My view:

```
<%= link_to "Remove this item", item_remove_path(@item),  class: 'button button-wide red-button', method: :patch %>
```

My `routes.rb`

```
resources :items do
 patch '/remove', to: 'items#remove', via: :patch
end
```

Comment: change to  `patch '/remove/:id', to: 'items#remove', on: :member`. If you skip `on: :member`, it will provide `params[:item_id]` instead of `params[:id]` - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What you are doing wrong:**

You have extended the restful resource `items`, to include `remove`, and you are expecting to get the `:id` in params. `params[:id]` is `nil` in the request which you can verify by seeing the rails development log for this request.

**How to fix this**:

**Way 1**:

Change to patch `'/remove', to: 'items#remove', on: :member`. Adding a [*member route*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes) will expose the `:id` of resource in request, enabling your request to process.

**Way 2**: 
Use your existing resource `patch '/remove', to: 'items#remove'`, but use `params[:item_id]` instead of `params[:id]` in request.

**Note**: You DO NOT have to expose `:id` by `patch '/remove/:id',`

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing item's id in items_controller.rb so you have to define a route that accepting id also as @kiddorails mention above in a comment.

```
patch '/remove/:id', to: 'items#remove', as: :remove_item, via: :patch
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the routes as follow

```
resouces :items do 
  member do
   patch :remove
  end
end
```

It will create `patch items/:id/remove` then you dont need to change anything in controller.